# Why Event Listener not getting applied to the inside function?

Tags: javascript, function, events, listener

I have some functions where one function has resize event listener and inside that function there is another function. But as the outer function has resize on it, I am hoping the inner function will be also called on resize event. But the inner function not working on resize. What is the problem here?

JAVASCRIPT

```
function chekon() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', upme);
  window.addEventListener('resize', upme);

  function upme() {
    var rome = document.getElementById("out-cmnt");
    var rect = rome.getBoundingClientRect();
    var poss = rect.top + window.scrollY;
    var iwwr = window.innerWidth;
    var koss = rect.bottom + window.scrollY;
    var loss = koss - poss;

    window.addEventListener('scroll', doso, false);

    function doso() {
      lopp = document.getElementById("Web_1920__1");
      hope = lopp.clientHeight;
      const meme = document.body.scrollHeight;
      const keke = hope / meme;
      const scsc = window.scrollY;
      var scmx = (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
      var innr = window.innerHeight;
      console.log("innr inner-height = ", innr);
    }
  }
}
chekon();
```

So here why the resize event listener not getting applied to the inner doso function on window resize? The doso function is inside the upme function. Do I need to apply resize event listener on both the functions even though the doso function is inside upme.

Comment: It's usually wrong to add an event listener inside another event listener. Every time the second event happens, you add another listener for the first event.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? It calculates a bunch of values, but never does anythinhg with them.

Comment: Can you please help me out with this? I need to optimize it. Yeah it calculates some stuffs. The full version is here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75158545/alternative-of-position-fixed-using-javascript-shows-weird-behavior-on-window-re <-- I am having a jittery laggy experience with it. The webpage to check on mac, windows https://elomymelo.com/soundcore-motion-boom-plus.html

Comment: @Barmar In my code, am I messing things up or emulating position fixed like this is jittery with browser limitations? the experience described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315278/laggy-jittery-user-experience-when-updating-top-bottom-value-using-javascript-sc any help regarding how to optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the window.addEventListener('scroll', doso, false); inside the upme function is only being executed once, when the upme function is first called. On subsequent calls to upme, the window.addEventListener('scroll', doso, false); line will not be executed again, and the doso function will not be registered as a scroll event listener. To make the doso function be called on each resize event, you need to move window.addEventListener('scroll', doso, false); outside of the upme function, so it can be executed each time upme is called.

Comment: Why won't it be executed on subsequent calls?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding the "scroll" event listener inside the "upme" function. This means that the "doso" function will only be registered as a "scroll" event listener once when the "upme" function is first called.

To resolve this issue, you should move the "scroll" event listener outside the "upme" function so that it will be registered every time the "upme" function is called, including when it's called as a result of a "resize" event.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
function chekon() {


  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', upme);
  window.addEventListener('resize', upme);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', doso, false);

  function upme() {
    var rome = document.getElementById("out-cmnt");
    var rect = rome.getBoundingClientRect();
    var poss = rect.top + window.scrollY;
    var iwwr = window.innerWidth;
    var koss = rect.bottom + window.scrollY;
    var loss = koss - poss;
  }

  function doso() {
    lopp = document.getElementById("Web_1920__1");
    hope = lopp.clientHeight;
    const meme = document.body.scrollHeight;
    const keke = hope / meme;
    const scsc = window.scrollY;
    var scmx = (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    var innr = window.innerHeight;
    console.log("innr inner-height = ", innr);
  }
}
chekon();
```

Comment: The `upme()` function is called when the page is first loaded because of `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', upme);`.

Comment: I think the code is correct, but your explanation doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Md Afzaal Khan you completely moved the doso function out of upme function. Now how the resize will work on both functions. They are separate functions now.

Comment: @SoumyaRoy  The "resize" event will work on both functions because they are both attached to the "resize" event listener on the window. When the window is resized, both the "upme" and "doso" functions will be called.